# Нужна помощь в написании функции JS

Tags: javascript

Есть задание - "Написать фунцию concat (), которая принимает любое количество аргументов и объединяет их в одну строку. Символ разделения по умолчанию "пробел", при необходимости нужно будет передать символ разделения"

написал такой код

```js
function concat(){
 var con1 = 'Привет';
 var con2 = 200;
 var con3 = 'Привет';
 
 if (con1 != "" && con2 != "" && con3 != "") {
  con1 = [con1, con2];
  con2 = [con3];
  var concat = con1.concat(con2);
  console.log(concat);
 }
}

concat();
```

но вот никак не могу понять как можно это сделать без использования массивов и задать разделитель. подскажите плз

Comment: твоя функция не объединяет **в одну строку**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принимает любое количество аргументов и преобразует все к строке. Первый аргумент функции, будет разделитель:

```js
function concat(splitme, ...rest) {
    return rest.join(splitme);
}
console.log(concat(' ', 1,'qwe',3,4,'zxc'));
```

Comment: Эм..... что?........зачем все эти магические действия?.......достаточно `rest.join(' ')`

Comment: согласен..что-то я перемудрил)

Comment: _при необходимости нужно будет передать символ разделения_

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку, если не требуется указывать разделитель, то все вообще элементарно:

```js
function concat() {
  return args.join(' ');
}

console.log('a');
console.log('a', 'b');
console.log('a', 'b', 'c');
```